# Problem on using the definition of Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

Consider the function: $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function on $[a,b]$. Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,c]$ for any $c\in (a,b)$. The question is to prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable on the interval $[a,b]$.

I am completely stuck on this question. I tried to use the tagged partition notion for Riemann integrals, but I couldn't figure out a way to start solving it. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Which definition of Riemann integrability do you use?

Comment: 29 minutes and no interaction whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,c]$ for any $c\in(a,b)$ choose $c$ so that $b-c<\frac{\epsilon}{4M}$ where $M$ is such that $|f|\le M$ for all $[a,b]$. This $M$ exists since $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. Take a partition, $P$, on $[a,b]$ such that $P=P'\cup[c,b]$ where $P'$ is a partition of $[a,c]$ such that $U(f,P')-L(f,P')<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which exists since $f$ is integrable over $[a,c]$. Then

$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\sum_{R\in P'}(M'_{f}-m'_{f})vol(R)+(M_{f}-m_{f})(b-c)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+2M\big(\frac{\epsilon}{4M}\big)=\epsilon$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary we can find such a partition of $[a,b]$ for every $\epsilon>0$. Hence $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

If you use the definition of Riemann Integrability of bounded functions in terms of the measure of their discontinuities then note that the measure of discontinuities of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is less than or equal to the measure of the the union of the  discontinuities of $f$ on $[a,b-\frac{1}{n}]$ over $n\in\mathbb{N}$ unioned with the set $\{b\}$. By this I mean, if we let $D$ be the discontinuities of $f$ on $[a,b]$ and $D_{n}$ be the discontinuities of $f$ on $[a,b-\frac{1}{n}]$, $m(D)\le m(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}D_{k}\cup\{b\})\le\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m(D_{k})+m(\{b\})=0$ using integrability of $f$ on $[a,b-\frac{1}{k}]$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and the fact that $m(\{b\})=0$. So $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.